# why doesn't the texture cover all the mesh

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv

I tried to cover the mesh with a brick texture but it didn't cover all the areas !
[image]

which left some ares without any texture

Comment: It's very difficult to see anything in your UV map / 3D view because you have selected everything, could you make another screen grab without the selection?

Comment: Could it be that not all the faces are assigned to this material (and so use another one) ? Also check that the texture hasn't any black borders.